# How many old scriptures i.e, original purana scripts are available besides Ramayana and Bhagavatam right now undamaged?

Tags: scripture, puranas

Since many Puranas were transferred to the next generations orally and written later on.
So, how many were written and been kept undamaged by priests till now? If available online share the link!!